# How to show balloon message on status bar item on Mac OS X

Tags: c, macos, statusbar, balloon

Apple has NSStatusItem  to manage the status bar item.
But it does not have API to show a balloon message from the status bar.

I know Java has `TrayIcon.displayMessage()`.

Does anyone know how to implement this balloon message with Xcode C/C++?

Answer (score 6):

No, balloon-style messages are not part of the standard OS X UI. Many third-party tools use the [Growl](http://growl.info/) framework for similar functionality.

Comment: Agreed. Balloons on the status tray are a Windows-specific thing.

Answer (score 2):

This might be what your looking for: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/03/04/using-maattachedwindow-with-an-nsstatusitem